# ¿Hay alguna forma de eliminar o desactivar la funcion de Hotspot (compartir internet) en android?

Tags: android

Estoy pensando en desarrollar una software para mi universidad, donde se manejaran los datos de los estudiantes que viven dentro de la institución. Me gustaría saber como desactivar o borrar la función de hotspot de un dispositivo android, ya que no conviene que quien lo use pueda tener acceso a esa funcionalidad.

He intentado investigar al respecto pero no he encontrado más que anuncios de app lockers. Intenté investigar un método para eliminar o desactivar la funcionalidad de hotspot. Sigo haciendolo, pero no he conseguido nada útil.Espero encontrar a alguien en esta comunidad de desarrolladores que pueda decirme como hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Qué intentaste investigar sobre esto, tienes algo de información?

Comment: Intenté investigar un método para eliminar o desactivar la funcionalidad de hotspot. Sigo haciendolo, pero no he conseguido nada útil.

Comment: Agrégalo a tu pregunta, por favor.

Comment: No puedes eliminar una funcionalidad del dispositivo. Si tuvieras permisos de súper usuario es diferente. Tal vez puedas deshabilitarlo o instalar un sistema operativo que no soporte la característica. Es más sensato hablar de restricción del uso de una aplicación en base a si esa característica está en funcionamiento. Por ejemplo, puedes detectar fácilmente si el Bluetooth está encendido. Lo que no sé es si requiere permisos de Bluetooth para ello.

Comment: Deberías aclarar qué es exactamente lo que quieres lograr.

Comment: Solamente quiero que el usuario que va a usar el teléfono no tenga la capacidad de generar un hotspot. De modo que no haya una mala administración de datos móviles por parte del usuario, ya que no es el objetivo de dicha parte de mi programa.